# Coq: Inequality test

Tags: if-statement, math, coq

There's a simple construct for conditional branching w/ an equality test in Coq:

```
Check ltac:(tryif unify 1 (S 0) then idtac "success" else idtac "fail"). (*success...*)
```

Is there a similar way to test `<` and/or `<=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `leb` and `ltb` functions from the standard library (they have notations `<=?` and `<?`).

```
Require Import Arith.

Check ltac:(match (eval cbv in (2 <? 5)) with
            | true =>  idtac "success"
            | false => idtac "fail" end).
```

Of course, this will fail in cases where the evaluation of the function gets stuck on a variable, e.g. if you have `x` in the context it will work to see that `3 < 5` and `1 < S (S x)`, but not for `S x < S (S x)`.

Comment: `Require Import Arith.
Definition e := 1.
Check ltac:(match (eval cbv in (S e <? S (S e))) with
            | true =>  idtac "success"
            | false => idtac "fail" end).` giveth "success...", so I'll consider the problem (for the time being) solved